# How close together do Earthshatter, Firestrike, and Charge have to be in order to get the "Storm, Earth and Fire" Achievement?

Tags: achievements, overwatch

As someone who's played a lot of Reinhardt, I'm wondering just how close together or how tightly-grouped my Earthshatter, Fire Strike, and Charge have to be in order to get the achievement for linking all three together.

As an example of one instance where it didn't give me the achievement, I just played a match on Numbani where I brought the hammer down, had to wait one second for my abilities to be off cooldown, threw the fire strike, and charged forward.  My first target couldn't have been more than a few meters away, and it definitely hit at least three people, I even got a triple-kill out of the deal, but still no achievement.

How tight together do these attacks need to be to trigger the achievement? Or is there some hidden part of the achievement I might not be triggering?

Comment: One thing that's not commonly known is you can hold down a button and it will be used ASAP.  You don't have to wait and try to press, which could introduce latency.  So hit Q, then *immediately* hold E, then hold Shift, even while the animations for the previous actions are still happening.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, you need to hit the enemies whilst they're still stunned from Earthshatter.